# Logical operations precedence and calculator program

Tags: boolean-algebra

I write the C library intended to be used in evaluating math expressions. It should support boolean algebra also. So at the moment I'm stuck with boolean precedence. I'm not a mathematician so that's my questions:

1) What is **expected** from a math **calculator** when it comes to boolean operations? The precedence as in C/Fortran language or it shouldn't has a precedence at all as in APL and user should use brackets? 
According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235586/logical-operators-priorities) in math it has the order as in convenient arithmetics: negation, conjunction, disjunction, implication, equivalence.

2) Is there any book where the boolean order is "chronicled in the paper"?

Thanks in advance.